# Nameserver does not advertise itself as nameserver

Tags: dns, dns-servers

Buying a Luxembough domain requires having a nameserver to point it to, before they allow you to buy the domain.

I have a 1 webserver (CentOS 7 with cPanel), and 1 nameserver (CentOS 7 with cPanel DNSonly).

On this site: https://www.dns.lu/en/support/checking-nameservers/ my domain has to score "Success" but i get "Failed" due to this message;

> Error: Nameserver 'ns1.i-strategi.dk' at address '93.104.214.152' does not advertise itself as nameserver
>
> Error: Nameserver 'ns2.i-strategi.dk' at address '37.61.223.179' does not advertise itself as nameserver

What exactly does "not advertise itself as a nameserver" mean? 
Both my dedicated nameserver and the webserver itself works perfect as a nameserver.

To run the same tests, you can use following details (must be lowercase):

Domain: hannibal.lu

Nameserver: `ns1.i-strategi.dk - 93.104.214.152`

Nameserver: `ns2.i-strategi.dk - 37.61.223.179`

The question here is: How do I advertise my nameserver as a nameserver?

Comment: Instead of running your own nameserver, you should get nameserver hosting.    Nameserver hosting can be as little as $10 USD per year.  It isn't expensive.  To run your own name servers you really should have several servers on different networks in different parts of the globe.   You should have domain names for those name servers under different top level domains.   You need to keep the servers up to date with latests software because DNS systems are some of the most attacked services.  Running a reliable nameserver system for yourself isn't cheap or easy.

Comment: Plus there is always the added impossibility of fixing a problem if you host your domain name on a NS that is a sub-domain of your domain name. Unless you really rally really know what you are doing, STOP!!

Comment: The reason i want to run my own nameservers (i have servers across different networks in the globe) is that the clients we are hosting on our webserver, can edit their DNS records in their webhosting controlpanel, which gets synchronizes automatically across our nameservers.

Comment: If you are in the business of offering nameserver hosting, then you obviously need to run your own servers, but I would also expect that you wouldn't be asking basic questions about how nameservers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask your nameservers about your domain name, they reply:

```
hannibal.lu.        86400   IN  NS  ns1.abusiness.dk.
hannibal.lu.        86400   IN  NS  ns2.abusiness.dk.
hannibal.lu.        86400   IN  NS  ns3.abusiness.dk.
```

And as you can see here for yourself, your nameservers' names given above are not included in the list of nameservers authoritative for your domain name as listed as NS records. This is a basic error which will forbid your domain name to resolve properly, so you need to fix it.

You may ask your registrar or prospective registrar for buying the domain name to also provide DNS service to you, so that you do not have to worry about it.

Comment: This is the current nameservers of the domain. I want to point the domain to my own nameservers, but dns.lu says that my nameservers "does not advertise themselves as nameservers". I want to fix the issue that they does not advertise themselves as a nameserver, and my question is why and how i can "advertise" as a nameserver.

Comment: Please reread my answer: your nameservers do not reply with themselves as NS records in the zone they serve. You have to fix the content of the zone.

Comment: Reading it again, i can see that i misunderstood your answer. Thank you, it made sense  :)